# Setting time and date for a variable date?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that I'm comparing to today date

```
  var x = new Date();
    x.setFullYear(2014, 6, 20);
    var today = new Date();
    hour = printTime("-8");
    console.log(x);
    if (x <=today){...
```

But is it possible to set it to a specific time too , like having 
`x.setFullYear(2014, 6, 20);` for 11pm on this date?

Comment: Check out the [`documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: date() objects already have time values built in, you just need to actually SET that time.

Comment: if you want x to be set to 11 pm you can simply do this x = new Date(2014, 6, 20, 23,00,00,00);

Comment: I don't see what is preventing you from passing these values directly as you construct the _Date_

Comment: @ Paul S. yup my mistake... edited it

Comment: @paul, its just what i saw here http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you really want to know, but far as I understand, you can use,

```
  var x = new Date();
  x.setHours(23, 00);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write some functions like this, I include a UTC version because *JavaScript* defaults to local time, which is different depending which country the viewer is in and on daylight savings.

```
function setAll(d) {
    var ymd = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, 4),
        hmsms = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 4);
    if (ymd.length) d.setFullYear.apply(d, ymd);
    if (hmsms.length) d.setHours.apply(d, hmsms);
}

function setUTCAll(d) {
    var ymd = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, 4),
        hmsms = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 4);
    if (ymd.length) d.setUTCFullYear.apply(d, ymd);
    if (hmsms.length) d.setUTCHours.apply(d, hmsms);
}
```

Then say you have `var d = new Date();` you could modify it's values using

```
d.toISOString(); // "2014-06-20T19:12:29.452Z"
        //   y, m, d, h, m, s, ms
setAll(d, 2000, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6); // months are zero-based in JavaScript
d.toISOString(); // "2000-02-02T03:04:05.006Z"
```